# How to delete all files/folders from a folder 'A' which are not present in the folder 'B', using Windows Batch Scripting?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-processing, xcopy, windows-scripting

How to delete all files/folders from a folder 'A' which are not present in the folder 'B', using Windows Batch Scripting?

For example, Folder A has following contents:
Dir1 -> File1
Dir2 (no files)
Dir3 -> File2
Dir4 (no files)
File3
File4
Dir5 -> File5

Folder B has following contents:
Dir3 -> File2
Dir4 (no files)
File3
File5

On running the script, following will be deleted from folder A:
Dir1, along with File1
Dir2
File4
Dir5, along with File5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
robocopy folderB folderA /purge /nocopy
```

This should remove all the elements in folderA not present in folderB without copying anything from folderB to folderA

Comment: Thankyou! Did the job! :)
If I don't add [/nocopy], will it make the two folders identical, without disturbing anything in folderB?

Comment: @user2494926 to make the two folders identical use `/mir` to mirror source. Anyway, source is never disturbed. All the changes are done in target.

Comment: Will "robocopy folderB folderA /purge" and "robocopy folderB folderA /mir" do exactly same things? I ran both commands, didn't notice any difference. Sorry, I'm new to windows batch commands.

Comment: @raptor, `/mir` = `/purge` + `/e` , that is, `/mir` include recursion over subfolders.

Comment: Alright, got it! Should have read the robocopy help earlier. Thanks!